# Pointing the website http root to a sub folder with htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache

How can I use RewriteRule to point the website http root to a sub folder?

I always use the rule below but now after upgrading to the latest wamp server, it does not working anymore. Why?

```
RewriteRule ^/?$  local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm [L,QSA]
```

I want to point, for instance,

`http://mysite.com/` to `http://mysite.com/local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm`

or in localhost wamp server, it should be like this,

`http://localhost/mysite/` to `http://localhost/mysite/local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm`

Any ideas?

And also,

`http://localhost/mysite/contact.htm` to 
`http://localhost/mysite/local/applications/bin/oldsite/contact.htm`

`http://localhost/mysite/about.htm` to 
`http://localhost/mysite/local/applications/bin/oldsite/about.htm`

**EDIT**

I managed to point the other pages to the specific locations with the rule below,

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.htm/?$  local/applications/bin/oldsite/$1.htm [L,QSA]
```

But still I cannot point

`http://localhost/mysite/` to `http://localhost/mysite/local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm`

Comment: I know this isn't what you want, but couldn't you put an `index.php` in the root folder and have it redirect?

Comment: Or just change the `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: sorry boj. please see my edit above. i have this old site that I have to keep until the new website is ready. and the new website programme is relying on the index.php in the root folder

Comment: For the local host you mention several files (contact.htm, index.htm,etc.), is it the same for the web site or the rule is only for `http://mysite.com/` to `...index.htm`?

Comment: yes these htm files are in the same folder as `index.htm` which is `oldsite`.

Comment: Re your last comment: on your localhost where you try to redirect /mysite/... use rewrite_base. Check the manual.

Comment: That's not quite clear yet. What happens with `http://mysite.com/any/number/of/folders/?query`, for example. Should that go to `http://mysite.com/local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm` just like that, removing the rest of the incoming segment path? The local part is clear, but the web server part not so much.

Comment: not sure if I undertand but I just need to point `http://localhost/mysite/` to `http://localhost/mysite/local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm` only. While `http://localhost/mysite/location/` will point to `index.php?url=location` by using this rule `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$  index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: This "http://mysite.com/ to http://mysite.com/local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm" in your question is what I am concerned about. Not the local server. What happens with the rest of the path: `http://mysite.com/more-path-segements`, for example, when the incoming URL holds `/more-path-segements`, are they lost, appended as a query to `index.htm`, what?

Comment: Aw I see. `http://mysite.com/more-path-segements` should be rewritten as `http://mysite.com/index.php?url=more-path-segements` it is only `http://mysite.com/` to be rewritten as  `mysite.com/local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm` - I think I should have used `rewrite` as the keyword here not `point`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATED

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#### localhost sets of rules
# No target file, go to index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   localhost     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mysite/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.htm   [NC]
RewriteRule  .  mysite/local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm  [R=301,L]

# Target file, go to file
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     localhost     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/mysite/([^\.]+)\.htm [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  .  mysite/local/applications/bin/oldsite/%1.htm  [R=301,L]

#### Live site set of rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   (?:www\.)?mysite\.com  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.htm            [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule  .  local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm [R=301,L]
```

The first sets of rules are for the local host and redirect permanently:

`http://localhost/mysite/filename.htm`

To:

`http://localhost/mysite/local/applications/bin/oldsite/filename.htm`

When `filename.htm` is not present in the incoming URL, `filename.htm` in the substitution URL is always `index.htm`

The string `mysite` is assumed to be a fixed string while `filename` is assumed to be a variable.

---

The second rule-set is for the web server and redirects permanently only

`http://mysite.com/`

To:

`http://mysite.com/local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm`

In the last case, if the incoming URL holds any additional path the rule is not applied.

For silent mapping, remove `R=301` from `[R=301,L]`.

Copy the above sets of rules into both .htaccess files in the local and remote root directories.

Comment: thank you faa. will try this out and let you know. many thanks! :-)

Comment: tested it but the root still not pointing to the specific location. I it is something wrong in my wampserver config, bcos this rule `RewriteRule ^/?$  local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm [L,QSA]` works exactly what I need at the live server. it is something to do with localhost - do you have any idea what should I look into in the wampserver config?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Not working in the local server or in the live server? If in the first one, try `RewriteBase /mysyte`  only for the local rule-set. ¿Why in the rule of your comment is there a `QSA` flag? That's not needed because there is no new query. It isn't in my answer. ¿Is there any of my rule-sets work?

Comment: yes your rule-sets work by directing the url/ path. `QSA` - i have no idea why i have been using it. what is it meant for actually? it is the localhost not working. but live server ok. wamp is strange.

Comment: `QSA` appends the old query to the new query but, of course, there has to be a new query and in this case there isn't. There is a common misconception of the purpose of that flag, though. Did you try changing the `RewriteBase` to `/mysite`? It would be very helpful to see the failing test URL and the corresponding redirected URL. Use `[R=301,L]` to see the results and please copy-paste them in a comment or in your question.

Comment: yes I tested with `RewriteBase /mysite` no error message on the localhost. it just won't `point http://localhost/mysite/` to `http://localhost/mysite/local/applications/bin/oldsite/index.htm`

Comment: but it get this error message `This web page has a redirect loop...has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.` when I want to access this page `http://localhost/mysite/contact.htm`

Comment: @lauthiamkok  Updated my answer. There was one condition missing: When the localhost incoming URL does not hold any file, it should go to `index.htm` and it was not going anywhere. Give it a try.

Comment: tested. no result on the localhost but yes on live server. I am sure that it is something wrong with my wampserver after upgrading. never mind as long as it works at the live server. thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started (untested):
Check in a condition whether the request does *not* point to a particular subfolder. If so, redirect the request to a subfolder. You can use in the target if you want. Instead of the HTTP Status 301 you can use another one if more appropriate.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(local/applications/bin/oldsite/.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http....n/subfolder/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. could you please have a look on my edit? thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you want to make the "oldsite" directory your [Document Root](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot) - right?

Comment: -1: How is this an answer to the question? You should ask clarifications in comments.

Comment: It's an answer because it seemed like the OP was trying to use the wrong tool for the job ... I'll ask for clarification in the comments in the future.